# Why does the shell sort return weird characters?

Tags: shell, sorting

I use the following command in order to sort the numerical key-value pairs in the input file. Moreover, I need only a single value for each key. In case there are more values for the same key, I intend to select the minimal one.

Input:

```
2 20
1 10
2 19
```

Output:

```
1 10
2 19
```

I use this shell command:

```
sort -n -k1 -k2 $MYFILE | sort -n -u -k1
```

Everything works fine for small inputs (hundreds of pairs). I tried generated a ~3GB file in order to measure time required to do the sorting but I was nothing but disappointed when the end of the output was similar to this:

```
%T3�����P����
           �6">�<�_!r�=_G�A������O<Ce۱��؉l6���3�$a8�����(_ē����7*���&���x���q&�n�PK����h�>�o�a��t�����,o�^��m��l�192�,����N)�$�)� *i�7�-������k�i���P�W�G
W��㛼�C��E���Ә3�)L
               �i�����Q�X����/-S�9�
                                    !�Y��EJ<�.�Q�SwMj��"�rÍI�f�y-P�ؚ;Yz
```

Where is the problem? Is the input too large and the sord command can't process it? Or maybe the pipe is the problem?

Comment: Could you post the command you used to generate the key and version and  author of the `sort` command you are using. My initial; thought is that it does not support wide characters and therefore has trouble processing binary data. But I need to know more about the data and the `sort` implementation.

Comment: @none Sort version: GNU coreutils 8.23; The generated file contains pairs of numbers that fits into C `unsigned long long` (8B), hence they have many digits...